# Convert utf-8 XML document to utf-16 for inserting into SQL

Tags: c#, xml, encoding

I have an XML document that has been created using utf-8 encoding.  I want to store that document in a sql 2008 xml column but I understand I need to convert it to utf-16 in order to do that.

I've tried using XDocument to do this but I'm not getting a valid XML result after the conversion.  Here is what I've tried to do the conversion on (Utf8StringWriter is a small class that inherits from StringWriter and overloads Encoding):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(utf8Xml);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
XmlWriter xml = XmlWriter.Create(writer, new XmlWriterSettings() 
                { Encoding = writer.Encoding, Indent = true });

xDoc.WriteTo(xml);

string utf16Xml = writer.ToString();
```

The data in the utf16Xml is invalid and when trying to insert into the database I get the error:

```
{"XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding"}
```

However the initial utf8Xml data is definitely valid and contains all the info I need.

UPDATE:
The initial XML is obtained by using XMLSerializer (with an Utf8StringWriter class) to create the xml string from an existing object model (*engine*).  The code for this is:

```
public static void Serialise<T>(T engine, ref StringWriter writer)
{
    XmlWriter xml = XmlWriter.Create(writer, new XmlWriterSettings() { Encoding = writer.Encoding });

    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(engine.GetType());

    xs.Serialize(xml, engine);
}
```

I have to leave this like this as that code is out of my control to change.

Before I even send the utf16Xml string to the failing database call I can view it via the Visual Studio debugger and I notice that the entire string is not present and instead I get a **string literal was not closed** error on the XML viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is on first line `XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(utf8Xml);`. Most likely you converted utf8 stream into a string (utf8xml), but encoding specified in the string is still utf-8, so XML reader fails. If it is true than load XML directly from stream using [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358684) instead of converting it to string first.

Comment: thanks for the comment.  I actually get given the string from another method that used XMLSerializer to create the XML in the first place so I don't have access to the stream itself.

Comment: So look at first characters - there is likely "encoding=....", if it is present or set to something different that UTF-16 here is your problem. I'd try to use XmlDocument.LoadXml in this case ...

Answer (score 2):

Set the encoding of the document to UTF-16 after you have parsed it from utf8xml

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(utf8Xml);
xDoc.Declaration.Encoding = "utf-16";
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
XmlWriter xml = XmlWriter.Create(writer, new XmlWriterSettings() 
                { Encoding = writer.Encoding, Indent = true });

xDoc.WriteTo(xml);

string utf16Xml = writer.ToString();
```

Comment: I just noticed I had the wrong string writer specified in my example.  I meant to only using StringWriter as I want the XML in utf-16 not utf-8.  Updated my question.

Comment: @dreza this line "xDoc.Declaration.Encoding = "utf-16";" should do the trcik for you then :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I had to do to make it work.  This just converts the XML to utf-16

```
string getUtf16Xml(System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{    
   System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xDoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
   xDoc.Declaration.Encoding = "utf-16";

   return xDoc.ToString();    
}
```

Then I can save the results to the DB.