# Opening an XML file and converting this to UTF-8

Tags: c#, xml, utf-8, ansi

I'm trying to open a xml file (ansi) and converting and saving it UTF-8.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;



class Test
{

public static void Main()
{
    string path = @"C:\test\test.xml";
    string path_new = @"C:\test\test_new.xml";

    try
    {
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path);        

          XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                           settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(path_new, settings))
            {
                reader.Save(writer);
            }





    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
    }
}

}
```

I'm getting an error 'System.Xml.XmlTextReader' does not contain a definition for 'Save' and no extension method 'Save' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.XmlTextReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What class am I missing here ? Is my code correct to do the job

EDIT:

Okay here another code that is giving me exception:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
 using System.Xml;



class Test
{

public static void Main()
{
    string path = @"C:\project\rdsinfo.xml";
    //string path_new = @"C:\project\rdsinfo_new.xml";

    try
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(path);



    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
    }
}
}
```

It's giving me an exception, invalid character in the given encoding.

Comment: well the error kinda says it all. XmlTextReader doesn't have a method Save() so you can't just type it and assume the compiler is going to "get" what you mean...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as simple as:

```
string path = @"C:\test\test.xml";
string path_new = @"C:\test\test_new.xml";

Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(false);
Encoding ansi = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

string xml = File.ReadAllText(path, ansi);

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

File.WriteAllText(
    path_new,
    @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" + xmlDoc.ToString(),
   utf8
);
```

Change the ANSI encoding (1252 in the sample) to whichever one your ANSI file is in - see
[list of encodings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this works but my arabic text come's out garbled. The original file is ansi. What should I add to help with it

Comment: You probably need to change the ANSI encoding to 1256 - see edit in the answer.

Comment: @Jonathan.. yes that works probably my mistake of ignoring that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `writer`, your instance of XmlTextWriter, to write this Xml to a file.  This class contains a number of methods that can be used to generate the output file (i.e. `writer.WriteString()`).

The reference can be found at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx

A better method can be found by utilizing the answer to this question:
[Convert utf-8 XML document to utf-16 for inserting into SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890450/convert-utf-8-xml-document-to-utf-16-for-inserting-into-sql)